# Why is my C++ getting slower after using parallelization with OpenMP

Tags: c++

I am trying to parallelize C++ code.

Below is part of my code.

I don't think there is an issue with race condition when I use parallelization here.

And the result is the same as the one without parallelization.

But somehow it took 1 second with parallelization per loop while it only takes 0.4 seconds without parallelization per loop.

So I was wondering whether I am using OpenMP wrong.

Is there any way I can speed up by using parallelization?

Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>       // power
#include <cmath>        // abs
#include <fstream>
#include <omp.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace chrono;

// Dynamically allocation with values(float)
void dallo_fn(float**** pMat, int Na, int Nd, int Ny) {
    float*** Mat = new float** [Na];
    for (int i = 0; i < Na; i++) {
        Mat[i] = new float* [Nd];
        for (int j = 0; j < Nd; j++) {
            Mat[i][j] = new float[Ny];
            fill_n(Mat[i][j], Ny, 1);
        }
    }
    *pMat = Mat;
}

// Dynamically allocation without values(float)
void dallo_fn0(float**** pMat, int Na, int Nd, int Ny) {
    float*** Mat = new float** [Na];
    for (int i = 0; i < Na; i++) {
        Mat[i] = new float* [Nd];
        for (int j = 0; j < Nd; j++) {
            Mat[i][j] = new float[Ny];
        }
    }
    *pMat = Mat;
}

// Dynamically allocation without values(int)
void dallo_fn1(int**** pMat, int Na, int Nd, int Ny) {
    int*** Mat = new int** [Na];
    for (int i = 0; i < Na; i++) {
        Mat[i] = new int* [Nd];
        for (int j = 0; j < Nd; j++) {
            Mat[i][j] = new int[Ny];
        }
    }
    *pMat = Mat;
}

// Utility function
float utility(float a, float a_f, float d, float d_f, float y, double sig, double psi, double delta, double R) {
    float C;
    C = y + a - a_f / R - (d_f - (1 - delta) * d);
    float result;
    if (C > 0) {
        result = 1 / (1 - 1 / sig) * pow(pow(C, psi) * pow(d_f, 1 - psi), (1 - 1 / sig));
    }
    else {
        result = -999999;
    }
    return result;
}


int main()
{
    
#if defined _OPENMP
    omp_set_num_threads(8);
#endif

    float duration;

    // Iteration Parameters
    double tol = 0.000001;
    int itmax = 200;
    int H = 15;

    // Model Parameters and utility function
    double sig = 0.75;
    double beta = 0.95;
    double psi = 0.5;
    double delta = 0.1;
    double R = 1 / beta - 0.00215;

    // =============== 2. Discretizing the state space =========================

    // Size of arrays
    const int Na = 1 * 91;
    const int Nd = 1 * 71;
    const int Ny = 3;

    // Variables for discretization of state space
    const float amin = -2;
    const float amax = 7;
    const float dmin = 0.01;
    const float dmax = 7;
    const float ymin = 0.5;
    const float ymax = 1.5;
    const float Ptrans[3] = { 0.2, 0.6, 0.2 };

    // Discretization of state space
    float ca = (amax - amin) / (Na - 1.0);
    float cd = (dmax - dmin) / (Nd - 1.0);
    float cy = (ymax - ymin) / (Ny - 1.0);

    float* A = new float[Na];
    float* Y = new float[Ny];
    float* D = new float[Nd];

    for (int i = 0; i < Na; i++) {
        A[i] = amin + i * ca;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < Nd; i++) {
        D[i] = dmin + i * cd;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < Ny; i++) {
        Y[i] = ymin + i * cy;
    }

    // === 3. Initial guesses, Variable initialization and Transition matrix ===

    // Initial guess for value function
    float*** V;
    dallo_fn(&V, Na, Nd, Ny);
    float*** Vnew;
    dallo_fn(&Vnew, Na, Nd, Ny);

    // Initialization of other variables
    float Val[Na][Nd];
    float** Vfuture = new float* [Na];
    for (int i = 0; i < Na; i++)
    {
        Vfuture[i] = new float[Nd];
    }
    float** temphoward = new float* [Na];
    for (int i = 0; i < Na; i++)
    {
        temphoward[i] = new float[Nd];
    }

    float*** Vhoward;
    dallo_fn0(&Vhoward, Na, Nd, Ny);
    float*** tempdiff;
    dallo_fn0(&tempdiff, Na, Nd, Ny);
    int*** maxposition_a;
    dallo_fn1(&maxposition_a, Na, Nd, Ny);
    int*** maxposition_d;
    dallo_fn1(&maxposition_d, Na, Nd, Ny);

    float** mg_A_v = new float* [Na];
    for (int i = 0; i < Na; i++)
    {
        mg_A_v[i] = new float[Nd];
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < Nd; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < Na; i++) {
            mg_A_v[i][j] = A[i];
        }
    }

    float** mg_D_v = new float* [Na];
    for (int i = 0; i < Na; i++)
    {
        mg_D_v[i] = new float[Nd];
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < Nd; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < Na; i++) {
            mg_D_v[i][j] = D[j];
        }
    }

    float***** Uvec = new float**** [Na];
    for (int i = 0; i < Na; i++) {
        Uvec[i] = new float*** [Nd];
        for (int j = 0; j < Nd; j++) {
            Uvec[i][j] = new float** [Ny];
            for (int k = 0; k < Ny; k++) {
                Uvec[i][j][k] = new float* [Na];
                for (int l = 0; l < Na; l++) {
                    Uvec[i][j][k][l] = new float[Nd];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < Na; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < Nd; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < Ny; k++) {
                for (int l = 0; l < Na; l++) {
                    for (int m = 0; m < Nd; m++) {
                        Uvec[i][j][k][l][m] = utility(A[i], mg_A_v[l][m], D[j], mg_D_v[l][m], Y[k], sig, psi, delta, R);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Value function iteration
    int it;
    float dif;
    float max;
    it = 0;
    dif = 1;

    // ================ 4. Value function iteration ============================

    while (dif >= tol && it <= itmax) {
        system_clock::time_point start = system_clock::now();
        it = it + 1;
        // V = Vnew;
        for (int i = 0; i < Na; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < Nd; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < Ny; k++) {
                    V[i][j][k] = Vnew[i][j][k];
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < Na; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < Nd; j++) {
                Vfuture[i][j] = 0;
                for (int k = 0; k < Ny; k++) {
                    Vfuture[i][j] += beta * Ptrans[k] * Vnew[i][j][k]; // + beta * Ptrans[1] * Vnew[i][j][1] + beta * Ptrans[2] * Vnew[i][j][2]; // Why is this different from Vfuture[i][j] += beta * Vnew[i][j][k] * Ptrans[k]; with for k
                }
            }
        }
        #pragma omp parallel for private(Val)     
        for (int a = 0; a < Na; a++) {
            for (int b = 0; b < Nd; b++) {
                for (int c = 0; c < Ny; c++) {
                    max = -99999;
                    for (int d = 0; d < Na; d++) {
                        for (int e = 0; e < Nd; e++) {
                            Val[d][e] = Uvec[a][b][c][d][e] + Vfuture[d][e];
                            if (max < Val[d][e]) {
                                max = Val[d][e];
                                maxposition_a[a][b][c] = d;
                                maxposition_d[a][b][c] = e;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Vnew[a][b][c] = max;
                }
            }
        }

        // Howard improvement
        for (int h = 0; h < H; h++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < Na; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < Nd; j++) {
                    for (int k = 0; k < Ny; k++) {
                        Vhoward[i][j][k] = Vnew[i][j][k];
                    }
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < Na; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < Nd; j++) {
                    for (int k = 0; k < Ny; k++) {
                        temphoward[i][j] = beta * Vhoward[maxposition_a[i][j][k]][maxposition_d[i][j][k]][0] * Ptrans[0]
                            + beta * Vhoward[maxposition_a[i][j][k]][maxposition_d[i][j][k]][1] * Ptrans[1]
                            + beta * Vhoward[maxposition_a[i][j][k]][maxposition_d[i][j][k]][2] * Ptrans[2];
                        Vnew[i][j][k] = temphoward[i][j] + Uvec[i][j][k][maxposition_a[i][j][k]][maxposition_d[i][j][k]];
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        // Calculate Diff
        dif = -100000;
        for (int i = 0; i < Na; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < Nd; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < Ny; k++) {
                    tempdiff[i][j][k] = abs(V[i][j][k] - Vnew[i][j][k]);
                    if (tempdiff[i][j][k] > dif) {
                        dif = tempdiff[i][j][k];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        system_clock::time_point end = system_clock::now();
        std::chrono::duration<float> sec = end - start;


        cout << dif << endl;
        cout << it << endl;
        cout << sec.count() << endl;
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < Ny; k++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < Na; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < Nd; j++) {
                cout << Vnew[i][j][k];
            }
            cout << '\n';
        }
    }
    cout << omp_get_max_threads() << endl;

}
```

Comment: Common mistakes when measuring/improving performance: use debug build for measurements instead release build (with optimization enabled), use of timer with poor resolution (check your `clock` resolution), improving code without doing profiling first, assuming that mutithreading is a golden hammer, disposing reverent results and do not noticed that thanks that compiler removed code which should be messured.

Comment: Making things parallel does not necessarily make them faster. You have to pay the extra cost of starting all the extra threads and then cleaning them up. So you have an extra fixed overhead. So the extra speedup you get must be worth the extra cost.

Comment: Also depending on your memory access, if multiple threads read/write in the same cache line you may also get poor performance (a.k.a false sharing)

Comment: Multithreading will generally only result in improved performance if the threads do not disturb each other too much. In this case, it seems that the threads disturb each other so much that the loop runs faster as a single thread than as multiple threads. My guess is that the reason for this is that the inner loops of all threads read and write to shared data, in this case the `Val` array. You might want to give each thread its own array `Val` array to read and write to.

Comment: @Andreas Wenzel Can I assign a unique array to each tread I am using? i.e if 'a' is less than 10, use Val1. if 'a' is greater than 10 but less than 20, use Val2

Comment: @ChangseokMa: You may want to take a look at the [`private` and `firstprivate` clauses of OpenMP](https://bisqwit.iki.fi/story/howto/openmp/#PrivateFirstprivateAndSharedClauses). These clauses allow you to specify which data should be shared by all threads and which data should be private to the threads. This allows you to specify that threads should get their own private copy of the array.

Comment: @Andreas Wenzel: If I use '#pragma omp parallel for private(Val)' I guess now I am using a copy of Val for each thread. Then does this mean, for example, if I am using 2 threads and Na, Nd, Ny are equal to 100, thread #1 use 0<=a<50 so that it writes from Vnew[0][0][0] to Vnew[49][99][99] and thread #2 writes from Vnew[50][0][0] to Vnew[99][99][99]. And after that, they merge these two results so that they have a complete version of Vnew[a][b][c]? Then, can I just make every variable inside the loop 'private' so that I can prevent threads from disturbing each other?

Comment: @ChangseokMa: If you use `private(Val)`, then each thread will have its own copy of the array `Val`. However, the array `Vnew` will still be shared among all threads (unless you also specify it as private). Therefore, there won't be any "merging" necessary for this array, because it never was split. Since all threads are writing to different parts of the array `Vnew`, it should not be a problem. [False sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing) may still be possible, but I doubt that this will be a problem, especially since it doesn't occur in the innermost loop.

Comment: @ChangseokMa: If you make all variables private, then you can be sure that there will be no shared data, and the threads won't be disturbing each other. However, if all variables are private, then the thread has no way of publishing its results and making these results visible to other threads. Therefore, you will generally need to have at least one shared variable/array, or you will at least have to do something else to ensure the results get published to shared data, for example by using the [`lastprivate` clause](https://bisqwit.iki.fi/story/howto/openmp/#LastprivateClause).

Comment: @Andreas Wenzel: Thanks Andreas, your comments helped me a lot. So that means if I need 'Vnew' 'maxposition_a' 'maxposition_d 'after loops I need to set them as a shared variable right? What if I make 'maxposition_a' as a private? I thought if this is the case, thread #1 (0<=a<50) writes from maxposition_a[0][0][0] to [49][99][99] and thread #2 (50<=a<100) writes from maxposition_a[50][0][0] to [99][99][99] and then merge these two arrays to get complete version of maxposition_a. But it looks like they cannot publish the results since the result from #1 is not visible to #2 and vice versa.

Comment: @ChangseokMa: Yes, `Vnew`, `maxposition_a` and `maxposition_d` should be shared among all threads. Sharing should not be a problem, because the threads will each be writing to different parts of the array, so there won't actually be any shared data (except maybe a small amount of [false sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing)). This does not apply to `Val`, as all threads will be writing to the same area. Therefore, `Val` should be `private` (or `lastprivate` if you need to keep the results of the final iteration).

Comment: @ChangseokMa: If you make `maxposition_a` private, as described in your previous comment, then you will be wasting a significant amount of memory, as every threads will have its own copy of the entire `maxposition_a` array. This is unnecessary, because every thread will only be using a small portion of that array. Also, if every thread has its own copy of the array, you will have the problem that these arrays will have to be merged. Although this would be possible (for example by having an additional shared version of the array), for the reasons stated above, this would not be meaningful.

Comment: @Andreas Wenzel: Sorry to keep bugging you but I have one more question. As you told me before, I am using 'for private(Val)'. When I use Visual Studio, I get the same result with or without parallelization so I guess this works well. However, when I compile the code with GCC I get different results (Using parallelization makes the result wrong). So I was wondering I should use different codes for different compilers...

Comment: @ChangseokMa: I believe the problem is the variable `max`, as every thread should also have its own copy of that variable, too. Currently, that variable is shared by all threads, so the threads overwrite each other's values. By the way, instead specifying that the variables are private in the `#pragma` directive, it would probably be easier to simply declare them inside the loop, so that the variables do not exist outside the loop. That way, these variables will automatically be private for every thread, so you don't have to use any `private` clause in the `#pragma` directive.

Comment: @ChangseokMa: Did my advice solve your problem? Are the results now also correct for the parallel version of your code?

Comment: @AndrasWenzel: Yes it solves the problem! Everything is perfect. As you said, the variable 'max' was the issue. Thank you so much. Can I ask you one more? Have you tried gpu parallelization with OpenMP? I need to make this code faster so I am thinking of using GPU parallelization. I thought changing '#pragma omp parallel for' to '#pragma omp target teams distribute parallel for' will be enough but doesn't seem working. So I was wondering whether I need to install something before I use GPU parallelization.

Comment: @ChangseokMa: Unfortunately, I have no experience with [GPGPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General-purpose_computing_on_graphics_processing_units) programming. I have read that the OpenMP standard offers some support for it since version 4.0, but I have no idea how well this is supported in implementations of OpenMP yet.

Comment: @ChangseokMa: If you are unable to get it to work with OpenMP, but are serious about improving your performance, you may want to look into [OpenCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL) or [CUDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA). The former is portable whereas the latter will only work on Nvidia GPUs.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel: Thank you I will look into those!